# Geometric Group Theory : An application of the Švarc-Milnor lemma to Riemannian Geometry via Fundamental groups

Tags: riemannian-geometry, fundamental-groups, geometric-group-theory

I've recently started studying Geometric Group Theory, and came across this interesting application of the Švarc-Milnor lemma to Riemannian Geometry.

Theorem)
Let $M$ be a compact connected Riemann manifold without boundary, $\tilde{M}$ the universal cover of $M$. Then the fundamental group $\pi_{1}(M)$ is finitely generated and is quasi-isometric to $\tilde{M}$.

So that by the above theorem, if the fundamental group of a compact connected Riemann manifold is not quasi-isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ ($\mathbb{H}^n$), then it does not admit a flat (hyperbolic) Riemannian metric.

Many of the lecture notes that I've read so far includes this application of the lemma, but none gives a rigid proof (probably due to the fact that these lectures are not meant to dive heavily into Riemannian Geometry).

I only have some background in Differential Manifolds (not quite yet into Riemann Manifolds), some Algebraic Topology (familiar with the universal cover and deck transformation). So I decided to try and prove this theorem as an exercise, but failed. I've broken down the proof in the following steps:

1. The universal cover $\tilde{M}$ of a Riemannian manifold $M$ (if there is one) is again a Riemannin manifold.
2. In fact, $\tilde{M}$ is a proper geodesic metric space.
3. The fundamental group  $\pi_{1}(M)$ acts on $\tilde{M}$ via deck transformation, and this action is isometric.
4. This action is properly discontinuous.
5. This action is cobounded (or equivalently cocompact).
6. Apply the Švarc-Milnor lemma.

Could someone help and explicitly write out the proof, or provide a reading material for each steps? I'd like to see an explicit proof and study it along with some necessary materials!

Here is the formal Švarc-Milnor lemma that I am looking at:

Lemma)
Let $X$ be a proper geodesic metric space and let group $G$ act by isometry on $X$. If the action is properly discontinuous and cobounded, then $G$ is finitely generated, and $G$ is quasi-isometric to $X$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Every textbook in geometric group theory will give a rigorous proof of this result. What did you read?

Comment: What in the outline did you need fleshed out?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I've read Clara Löh's Geometric Group Theory, Alessandro Sisto's Lecture Notes!

Comment: @PaulPlummer Well accepting step 1 and 2, step 3 came easy.

Comment: For step 4, I first tried to prove that if the space is locally compact, then an action is properly discontinuous (in the sense that orbit of any compact set K intersects with K for only finitely many elements of G) iff  for every x , there exists an open neighborhood s.t. the orbit of the neighborhood intersects with itself for only finitely many elements of G. Next I tried proving that if an action is free and properly discontinuous , then the for all points in X, there exists a neighborhood s.t. the orbit of this neighborhood never intersects with itself (except for the trivial orbit).

Comment: I read that some authors refer to action with the last property I mentioned as "open covering actions", as $ \pi : X \rightarrow X/G$ is a covering map iff the action has the property mentioned.

Comment: For step 5, I tried proving action is cobounded iff it is cocompact; so that $\tilde{X}/ \pi_1 (X) = \tilde{X} / Aut(p) = X$ is compact. Am I on the right track so far?